# Excel If Condition on Multiple Cells

Tags: excel-formula

I have been trying to get an excel formula work for over a day now. My Scenario is as below:

Department---------Sev1-----Sev2-------RAG

IT-------------------------0---------0---------Green

Transport --------------0---------2-----------Red

Admin-------------------0-------4 -------------Red

If Sev1 and Sev2 are both 0 then RAG should display text "green"

If Sev1 is more than 0 then RAG should display text "Red"

If Sev1 is 0 and Sev2 is 1 then RAG should display text "Amber"

If Sev1 is 0 and Sev2 is more than 1 then RAG should display text "Red"

Any help would me much appreciated!

Thanks

Joe

Comment: You'll get more satisfaction out of figuring it out vs me telling you the answer. check this out http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_nested.php

Comment: Hello Ross, Thank You so much, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Sev1 is column B, Sev2 is column C

Also assuming Sev1, Sev2 are never negative, and Sev2 is never a fraction between 0 and 1.

```
if(B2>0, "Red", if(C2=0, "green", if(C2=1, "Amber", "Red")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest your if formulas. Assuming that your header starts in A1 then:

```
=IF(B2 > 0, "Red",IF(C2 = 1, "Amber", IF( C2 > 1, "Red", "green")))
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, Thanks for the quick answer, this formula worked for me too!